# Nullable predicate in android ROOM

Tags: android, android-room

I have Dao and Query to load all Item by parentId

```
@Entity(
        indices = @Index("parent_id"),
        foreignKeys = @ForeignKey(entity = Parent.class, parentColumns = "id", childColumns = "parent_id")
)
public class Item extends BaseEntity {
    @ColumnInfo(name = "parent_id")
    private String parentId;
    private String name;

    ...
}

@Dao
public interface ItemDao {
   Item @Query("SELECT * FROM Item WHERE parent_id = :parentId")
   LiveData<List<Item>> loadByParentId(String parentId);
}
```

This works while parentId != null. Query with parentId = null return 0 Items. But I want to load all Item where parentId equal null too.

I find this solution:

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM Item WHERE parent_id = :parentId OR (:parentId IS NULL AND parent_id IS NULL)")
LiveData<List<Item>> loadByParentId(String parentId);
```

Can there be a better solution?

Comment: can it be something related to `parent_id` being nullable or not!

Comment: parent_id is nullable

Answer (score 0):

Can you try using conditional query, something like this:
`SELECT * FROM product WHERE parent_id = @ParentID OR ISNULL(@ParentID, '') = ''`